# Microsoft SQL Server uses outdated values in stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Stored Procedure which is never ending because of some values which are cached. But that is just a guess after debugging the procedure.

```
    while @poid is not NULL
    BEGIN

        Update Item set Sales = (Select Sales from V_ITEM_Hierarchy where POID=@poid) where ItemID=@poid

        Select @poid = i.ItemID
        from V_ITEM_Hierarchy t inner join Item i on (t.POID = i.POID)
        where ( abs(coalesce(t.Sales,0)-coalesce(i.Sales,0)) > 0.0001

    END
```

I update the value "Sales" in Table Item with the Sales value of a view called "V_ITEM_Hierarchy" and then look again for values which are different. When I debug through the procedure the select-statement always returns the same value even if the Sales values are not different anymore because they were updated.

I tried to insert the command "DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS" but the select-statement still returns old values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second query does not return any rows the value of @poid will NOT be updated. What you need is

```
while @poid is not NULL
BEGIN

    Update Item set Sales = (Select Sales from V_ITEM_Hierarchy where POID=@poid) where ItemID=@poid

    set @poid = null

    Select @poid = i.ItemID
    from V_ITEM_Hierarchy t inner join Item i on (t.POID = i.POID)
    where ( abs(coalesce(t.Sales,0)-coalesce(i.Sales,0)) > 0.0001

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be much better off changing this to a cursor because you will always have the possibility of an endless loop the way it is written now.

```
DECLARE @poid INT

DECLARE item_cursor CURSOR FOR
 Select i.ItemID
   from V_ITEM_Hierarchy t inner join Item i on (t.POID = i.POID)
  where ( abs(coalesce(t.Sales,0)-coalesce(i.Sales,0)) > 0.0001

OPEN item_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @poid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
     Update Item set Sales = (Select Sales from V_ITEM_Hierarchy where POID=@poid) where ItemID=@poid

    FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @poid
  END

DEALLOCATE item_cursor
```

Comment: I am afraid V_ITEM_Hierarchy takes its values out of the Item table, which means every time the Item table is changed the values in V_ITEM_Hierarchy can be different.

Comment: Ah, that's a bummer. One thing I have seen is views returning very strange data when the data structure of one of the tables in the view changes, but the view isn't recompiled.